# inverse of operator

Tags: operator-theory, differential-operators, unbounded-operators

I want to calculate the inverse of the operator
 $T=-\frac{\partial^{2}  }{\partial x^{2}}-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial y^{2}}-(x^{2}+y^{2})+2( x\frac{\partial }{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial  }{\partial x}  )$ with domain $D=C^{\infty}_{c}$.
Can you give me some methods, thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure your "2" should not read "2i" (to make $T$ Hermitian)

Comment: if we have   "2i"  the operator $T$ becomes self-adjoint, my operator with 2 there is not "2i"

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use power series. Since we're in $C^{\infty}$ it's viable, (not sure about convergence though.)

$T^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (T-1)^n$ from the geometric series

$\frac{1}{1+T} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$

Comment: some more motivation would also be helpful; do you need the Green's function for some application?